# Windows10 VM on Windows10 Host Freezes/BSOD IRQL NOT LESS OR EQUAL

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I got a new SSD for my laptop. I copied my VMs to my new Windows 10 installation on this device.

I believe the guest OS is Windows 10 version 1909 as was the host on the installation on the old SSD. Currently running Version 1909 (OS Build 18363.836).

I was running VirtualBox-6.1.4-136177 before and on the new install until I tried updating to VirtualBox-6.1.8-137981 to fix the issue with no luck.

The machine is slow, has wierd graphics flickering issues, and gets BSOD saying IRQL NOT LESS OR EQUAL.

I never had any issues with the old SSD, I never got BSOD until I ran it off the new SSD.

I also copied the %HOMEPATH%.VirtualBox folder. All my VMs show up fine. I am able to launch the VM as I was before, minus the BSOD.

I added a new VirtualDisk.vdi file and installed Windows 10 on that with the other vdi as a USB device to access my data from it.

I never got a BSOD since using a the new VDI Virtual Disk file, but it's still slow. Before the performance was great.

Checking the disk for errors using the tool in Tools on the tab on the properties for drive C:\ and using the chkdsk C:\ command says the drive has no errors.

I have a dual core (4 thread) CPU and 8GB of RAM and the VM was 2GB allocated.

Running the VM off the old SSD works OK, so does running a new Windows 10 VM I made to test Win10-v2004. Also, they are running at the same time!!!

https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=98376#p477034

Update: Here is text from the Nirsoft BlueScreenView Program:

```
==================================================
Dump File         : 060720-22203-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 6/7/2020 8:39:04 AM
Bug Check String  : IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL
Bug Check Code    : 0x0000000a
Parameter 1       : 00000000`00000001
Parameter 2       : 00000000`00000002
Parameter 3       : 00000000`00000000
Parameter 4       : fffff800`80785733
Caused By Driver  : ntoskrnl.exe
Caused By Address : ntoskrnl.exe+1c14e0
File Description  : NT Kernel & System
Product Name      : Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
Company           : Microsoft Corporation
File Version      : 10.0.18362.592 (WinBuild.160101.0800)
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+1c14e0
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\Windows\Minidump\060720-22203-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 1
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 18362
Dump File Size    : 334,308
Dump File Time    : 6/7/2020 8:40:55 AM
==================================================
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SuperUser. You may want to grab a tool like WinDbg or [BlueScreenView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) to be able to give us more details. As it stand there are by far too little details to help here.  An example of things that could be different: perhaps one of those VMs has virtual guest tools installed and so uses the hosts graphics adapter differently from the others. Basically the above tools could take a guess at the module (driver) causing the BSOD and they'd enable getting more details. Host VGA drivers are all up-to-date?

Comment: I get a warning about invalid settings because I am using a GFX adapter other than the recommended one (I am sure I just used the default selected). I switched from VBoxVGA to VBoxSVGA and it made no difference. I am running the VM off an the old SSD with those settings reverted and it's working fine there.

Comment: Thanks for welcoming me :)

Comment: Do those tools contain sensitive details (homepath/username, hostname, etc.)

Comment: the dumps (whether minidumps or full dumps) are bound to contain sensitive details, but the analysis shown by the mentioned tools is textual and so you can redact it before posting it.

Comment: I updated the question with info from Nirsoft BlueScreenView

Comment: According to the info (which, however, doesn't contain as much info as `!analyze -v`), `ntoskrnl.exe` is the culprit. That's fairly unusual. What 3rd-party software are you using? I'd expect there to be some 3rd-party software which uses some hooking techniques. While Patchguard exists to prevent tampering, a number of techniques are known to get around this.

Comment: It says ntoskrnl  is part of Windows, what makes you think it's 3rd party software? It mainly runs OneDrive. I just had Windows running (OneDrive isn't 3rd party) and NextCloud. I wasn't using any specific application when it crashed and it's the same software that was running on the VM before the copy...

Comment: Huh? Where did I say `ntoskrnl.exe` is third-party software? That particular bugcheck code means that some code attempted to do something which wasn't allowed at that IRQL. One common instance of this is code accessing _paged_ memory when running at a too high IRQL (and thus there not being a chance of the memory being paged in). Now this particular bugcheck code occurred a lot in times of XP. And during that time mostly in third-party code. Hooks would explain faulty code attributed to `ntoskrnl.exe`, because the kernel has come a long way in terms of stability.

Comment: Not ruling out that `ntoskrnl.exe` is the culprit, but chances are that some other code has hooked stuff. But without access to the actual minidump there is little more one could state. Everything beyond this is guesswork.